# Frequent System Hangs Requiring Hard Reboot

Tags: 20.04, freeze

I am a novice, relatively new to Ubuntu.  In the past few days I have had numerous hangs using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a new ASUS ROG Crosshair VIII Hero motherboard with AMD Ryzen 9 3950X CPU that ran for several months prior with no issues. The OS is on an M.2 SSD. Other than Updates from Software Updater, I have not done software installs, and the hangs do not seem to have circumstances in common. The system will be working fine and suddenly hang and require a hard reboot after which it seems to be fine once more.  I have tried to troubleshoot this by looking at Syslogs but I have not been able to deduce what the problem is.  I am going to attach 4 brief log segments that cover what happened just prior to the past four hangs.  I do not see anything that points to a particular app.  If anyone can point me in the direction of where to look to solve this problem I would very much appreciate the help.

**FIRST HANG:**

```
Dec  1 10:16:20 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45678]: [00007f3035ff9f70] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 9000000)
Dec  1 10:16:20 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45678]: [00007f3035ff9f70] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 21918429628 for FFmpeg
Dec  1 10:16:20 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45678]: [h264 @ 0x7f3036077e00] get_buffer() failed
Dec  1 10:16:20 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45678]: [h264 @ 0x7f3036077e00] thread_get_buffer() failed
Dec  1 10:16:20 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45678]: [h264 @ 0x7f3036077e00] decode_slice_header error
Dec  1 10:16:20 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45678]: [h264 @ 0x7f3036077e00] no frame!
Dec  1 10:16:28 vishnu gnome-shell[6852]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x6600008 specified for 0x6600079.
Dec  1 10:16:47 vishnu gnome-shell[6852]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x5000008 specified for 0x50001af.
Dec  1 10:16:49 vishnu systemd[6593]: Started snap.vlc.vlc.6f29d6c5-e5cc-44d1-973a-bd74a2502bc2.scope.
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[46051]: libGL error: failed to create dri screen
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[46051]: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[46051]: libGL error: failed to create dri screen
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[46051]: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: [00005618c16e8a00] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu vlc[45961]: Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to create dri screen
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to create dri screen
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu kernel: [21925.352182] audit: type=1400 audit(1638379010.369:151): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.vlc.vlc" name="/etc/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/" pid=45961 comm="vlc" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to create dri screen
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to create dri screen
Dec  1 10:16:50 vishnu org.freedesktop.FileManager1[45961]: libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
Dec  1 10:17:01 vishnu CRON[46176]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

**SECOND HANG:**

```
Dec  1 15:28:27 vishnu systemd[6561]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Dec  1 15:28:31 vishnu tracker-miner-f[6569]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 (file:///home/j2b/Downloads/Unconfirmed%20207265.crdownload) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url
Dec  1 15:28:31 vishnu tracker-miner-f[6569]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url
Dec  1 15:28:33 vishnu tracker-miner-f[6569]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 (file:///home/j2b/Downloads/Mortage%20890879978227995.nzb) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url
Dec  1 15:28:33 vishnu tracker-miner-f[6569]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu dbus-daemon[1405]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.168' (uid=1000 pid=9966 comm="pan " label="unconfined")
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu dbus-daemon[1405]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu kernel: [17161.800340] audit: type=1107 audit(1638397714.195:154): pid=1405 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.169" pid=16207 label="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" peer_pid=21638 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu kernel: [17161.800340]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu kernel: [17161.800399] audit: type=1107 audit(1638397714.195:155): pid=1405 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.169" pid=16207 label="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" peer_pid=21638 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu kernel: [17161.800399]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu kernel: [17161.800451] audit: type=1107 audit(1638397714.195:156): pid=1405 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.169" pid=16207 label="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" peer_pid=21638 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  1 15:28:34 vishnu kernel: [17161.800451]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

**THIRD HANG:**

```
Dec  1 21:30:01 vishnu CRON[26873]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Dec  1 21:31:57 vishnu systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Dec  1 21:31:57 vishnu anacron[26883]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-12-01
Dec  1 21:31:57 vishnu anacron[26883]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Dec  1 21:31:57 vishnu systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Dec  1 21:37:54 vishnu NetworkManager[1403]: <info>  [1638419874.7466] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Dec  1 21:37:54 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:37:54] offline
Dec  1 21:37:54 vishnu dbus-daemon[1400]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=1403 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec  1 21:37:54 vishnu systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec  1 21:37:54 vishnu dbus-daemon[1400]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  1 21:37:54 vishnu systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec  1 21:37:58 vishnu NetworkManager[1403]: <info>  [1638419878.5890] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec  1 21:37:58 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:37:58] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  1 21:37:58 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:37:58] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  1 21:37:58 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:37:58] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  1 21:37:59 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:37:59] online
Dec  1 21:38:08 vishnu systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec  1 21:38:15 vishnu NetworkManager[1403]: <info>  [1638419895.7456] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Dec  1 21:38:15 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:38:15] offline
Dec  1 21:38:15 vishnu dbus-daemon[1400]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=1403 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec  1 21:38:15 vishnu systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec  1 21:38:15 vishnu dbus-daemon[1400]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  1 21:38:15 vishnu systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec  1 21:38:21 vishnu NetworkManager[1403]: <info>  [1638419901.3761] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec  1 21:38:21 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:38:21] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  1 21:38:21 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:38:21] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  1 21:38:21 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:38:21] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  1 21:38:22 vishnu whoopsie[6363]: [21:38:22] online
Dec  1 21:38:31 vishnu systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

**FOURTH HANG:**
Dec  2 11:35:41 vishnu kernel: [15070.726112] audit: type=1400 audit(1638470141.006:157): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" name="/proc/16535/mounts" pid=16535 comm="ghb" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Dec  2 11:35:42 vishnu kernel: [15072.435444] audit: type=1400 audit(1638470142.714:158): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" name="/proc/16535/mountinfo" pid=16535 comm="ghb" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Dec  2 11:35:48 vishnu kernel: [15078.511472] kauditd_printk_skb: 3 callbacks suppressed
Dec  2 11:35:48 vishnu kernel: [15078.511475] audit: type=1400 audit(1638470148.790:162): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" name="/proc/16535/mounts" pid=16535 comm="ghb" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Dec  2 11:35:49 vishnu kernel: [15078.728512] audit: type=1400 audit(1638470149.006:163): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" name="/proc/16535/mountinfo" pid=16535 comm="ghb" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Dec  2 11:35:49 vishnu kernel: [15078.728519] audit: type=1400 audit(1638470149.006:164): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" name="/proc/16535/mounts" pid=16535 comm="ghb" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Dec  2 11:34:50 vishnu gnome-shell[6793]: message repeated 7 times: [ Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4c00008 specified for 0x4c0006d.]
Dec  2 11:36:03 vishnu dbus-daemon[6573]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gnome/SessionManager" interface="org.gnome.SessionManager" member="Inhibit" mask="send" name=":1.35" pid=16535 label="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" peer_pid=6779 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  2 11:36:03 vishnu kernel: [15093.442175] audit: type=1400 audit(1638470163.721:165): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" name="/proc/16535/mounts" pid=16535 comm="ghb" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Dec  2 11:37:15 vishnu gnome-shell[6793]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
Dec  2 11:37:32 vishnu gnome-shell[9640]: [9641:9641:1202/113732.200264:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 187.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  2 11:37:32 vishnu gnome-shell[9640]: [9641:9641:1202/113732.200573:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 187.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  2 11:37:32 vishnu gnome-shell[9640]: [9641:9641:1202/113732.200890:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 187.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  2 11:44:05 vishnu dbus-daemon[1366]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.177' (uid=1000 pid=22269 comm="file-roller /media/j2b/M/D/b_pan download/a.b.movi" label="unconfined")
Dec  2 11:44:05 vishnu systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu dbus-daemon[1366]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu kernel: [15575.743642] audit: type=1107 audit(1638470646.022:166): pid=1366 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.178" pid=16535 label="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" peer_pid=22293 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu kernel: [15575.743642]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu kernel: [15575.743674] audit: type=1107 audit(1638470646.022:167): pid=1366 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.178" pid=16535 label="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" peer_pid=22293 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu kernel: [15575.743674]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu kernel: [15575.743717] audit: type=1107 audit(1638470646.022:168): pid=1366 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/hostname1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.178" pid=16535 label="snap.handbrake-jz.ghb" peer_pid=22293 peer_label="unconfined"
Dec  2 11:44:06 vishnu kernel: [15575.743717]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Dec  2 11:44:36 vishnu systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231499] general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x27bb90df0d17aa3b: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231509] CPU: 11 PID: 6657 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G           OE     5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231513] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO, BIOS 2311 10/16/2020
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231516] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231526] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 b3 51 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231529] RSP: 0018:ffff9d4d02b03898 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231532] RAX: 27bb90df0d17aa3b RBX: ffff89bf80f48170 RCX: 000000008000900b
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231534] RDX: 000000000025e47e RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231536] RBP: ffff9d4d02b038d0 R08: ffff89c68ecf10c0 R09: 000000000000001a
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231538] R10: ffff9d4d02b03a5d R11: 000000000000001a R12: 27bb90df0d17aa0b
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231540] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff89bf80043a00
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231542] FS:  00007f051b0f1ec0(0000) GS:ffff89c68ecc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231544] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231547] CR2: 000055679fb8c048 CR3: 000000019eace000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231549] Call Trace:
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231555]  ? nvif_object_ctor+0x83/0x160 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231703]  nvif_object_ctor+0x83/0x160 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231756]  nvif_mem_ctor_type+0xc2/0x1a0 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231807]  ? nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x76f/0x7a0 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231874]  ? nvkm_vmm_node_insert+0x60/0x70 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.231936]  nouveau_mem_vram+0xe3/0x180 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232004]  nouveau_vram_manager_new+0x74/0x90 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232066]  ttm_resource_alloc+0x45/0x50 [ttm]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232073]  ttm_bo_mem_space+0xe6/0x330 [ttm]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232079]  ttm_bo_validate+0xf9/0x160 [ttm]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232086]  ttm_bo_init_reserved+0x2b7/0x340 [ttm]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232092]  ttm_bo_init+0x61/0xe0 [ttm]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232098]  ? nouveau_bo_del_io_reserve_lru+0x60/0x60 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232159]  nouveau_bo_init+0xb8/0xd0 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232217]  ? nouveau_bo_del_io_reserve_lru+0x60/0x60 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232275]  nouveau_gem_new+0x7d/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232331]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x100/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232370]  nouveau_gem_ioctl_new+0x5b/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232423]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x100/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232475]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232510]  drm_ioctl+0x257/0x410 [drm]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232533]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x100/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232589]  ? ttwu_do_activate+0xb7/0x4a0
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232595]  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x66/0xc0 [nouveau]
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232649]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x91/0xc0
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232653]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232657]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232660] RIP: 0033:0x7f051b48450b
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232663] Code: 0f 1e fa 48 8b 05 85 39 0d 00 64 c7 00 26 00 00 00 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 55 39 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232665] RSP: 002b:00007ffc2698c1e8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232668] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffc2698c240 RCX: 00007f051b48450b
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232669] RDX: 00007ffc2698c240 RSI: 00000000c0306480 RDI: 000000000000000e
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232671] RBP: 00000000c0306480 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00007f051b558b80
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232672] R10: 0000000000000007 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007ffc2698c240
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232673] R13: 000000000000000e R14: 0000557db0215420 R15: 0000000000001000
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232676] Modules linked in: ip6table_filter ip6_tables vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core edac_mce_amd nouveau kvm_amd snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm kvm joydev input_leds drm_ttm_helper ttm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel snd_rawmidi crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_seq rapl drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer ucsi_ccg cec typec_ucsi rc_core snd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof mxm_wmi typec efi_pstore k10temp soundcore sysimgblt ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel nct6775 hwmon_vid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp ses enclosure scsi_transport_sas hid_logitech_dj
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232736]  hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage mfd_aaeon asus_wmi sparse_keymap video crc32_pclmul igb ahci libahci i2c_nvidia_gpu i2c_algo_bit dca r8169 xhci_pci nvme xhci_pci_renesas i2c_piix4 realtek nvme_core wmi
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.232752] ---[ end trace fdac69185727f5cd ]---
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459508] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459553] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 b3 51 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459558] RSP: 0018:ffff9d4d02b03898 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459564] RAX: 27bb90df0d17aa3b RBX: ffff89bf80f48170 RCX: 000000008000900b
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459567] RDX: 000000000025e47e RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459571] RBP: ffff9d4d02b038d0 R08: ffff89c68ecf10c0 R09: 000000000000001a
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459573] R10: ffff9d4d02b03a5d R11: 000000000000001a R12: 27bb90df0d17aa0b
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459575] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff89bf80043a00
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459579] FS:  00007f051b0f1ec0(0000) GS:ffff89c68ecc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459583] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  2 11:44:59 vishnu kernel: [15629.459585] CR2: 000055679fb8c048 CR3: 000000019eace000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722498] general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x27bb90df0d17aa3b: 0000 [#2] SMP NOPTI
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722517] CPU: 11 PID: 22014 Comm: ghb Tainted: G      D    OE     5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722521] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO, BIOS 2311 10/16/2020
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722524] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722537] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 b3 51 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722541] RSP: 0018:ffff9d4d04a3fca8 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722546] RAX: 27bb90df0d17aa3b RBX: 0000000008000002 RCX: 0000000000000001
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722548] RDX: 000000000025e484 RSI: 0000000000404cc0 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722550] RBP: ffff9d4d04a3fce0 R08: ffff89c68ecf10c0 R09: 0000000000000000
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722551] R10: ffffffffae569190 R11: 0000000000000029 R12: 27bb90df0d17aa0b
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722552] R13: 0000000000404cc0 R14: ffff89bf8cacbf80 R15: ffff89bf80043a00
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722554] FS:  00007f377b7ce700(0000) GS:ffff89c68ecc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722555] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722557] CR2: 000055679fb8c048 CR3: 000000010720a000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722559] Call Trace:
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722564]  ? inotify_handle_inode_event+0x7e/0x210
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722577]  inotify_handle_inode_event+0x7e/0x210
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722580]  fsnotify_handle_inode_event.isra.0+0x7c/0xa0
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722585]  fsnotify+0x4d2/0x550
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722587]  __fsnotify_parent+0x203/0x310
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722590]  vfs_write+0x16d/0x280
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722597]  ? vfs_write+0x16d/0x280
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722599]  ksys_write+0x67/0xe0
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722602]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722605]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722611]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722620] RIP: 0033:0x7f3b386833a7
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722624] Code: 44 00 00 41 54 55 49 89 d4 53 48 89 f5 89 fb 48 83 ec 10 e8 5b fd ff ff 4c 89 e2 41 89 c0 48 89 ee 89 df b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 35 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 94 fd ff ff 48
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722625] RSP: 002b:00007f377b7cd0c0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722627] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000017 RCX: 00007f3b386833a7
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722628] RDX: 0000000000040000 RSI: 00007f36b7f3a7c0 RDI: 0000000000000017
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722629] RBP: 00007f36b7f3a7c0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000040000
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722631] R10: e1372dbcf3824e35 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000040000
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722632] R13: 0000000000040000 R14: 0000000000040000 R15: 0000000000000005
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722635] Modules linked in: ip6table_filter ip6_tables vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core edac_mce_amd nouveau kvm_amd snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm kvm joydev input_leds drm_ttm_helper ttm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel snd_rawmidi crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_seq rapl drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device snd_timer ucsi_ccg cec typec_ucsi rc_core snd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof mxm_wmi typec efi_pstore k10temp soundcore sysimgblt ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel nct6775 hwmon_vid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp ses enclosure scsi_transport_sas hid_logitech_dj
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722725]  hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage mfd_aaeon asus_wmi sparse_keymap video crc32_pclmul igb ahci libahci i2c_nvidia_gpu i2c_algo_bit dca r8169 xhci_pci nvme xhci_pci_renesas i2c_piix4 realtek nvme_core wmi
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15629.722755] ---[ end trace fdac69185727f5ce ]---
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159898] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159941] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 b3 51 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159947] RSP: 0018:ffff9d4d02b03898 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159955] RAX: 27bb90df0d17aa3b RBX: ffff89bf80f48170 RCX: 000000008000900b
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159958] RDX: 000000000025e47e RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159960] RBP: ffff9d4d02b038d0 R08: ffff89c68ecf10c0 R09: 000000000000001a
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159964] R10: ffff9d4d02b03a5d R11: 000000000000001a R12: 27bb90df0d17aa0b
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159967] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff89bf80043a00
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159970] FS:  00007f377b7ce700(0000) GS:ffff89c68ecc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159974] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  2 11:45:02 vishnu kernel: [15632.159976] CR2: 000055679fb8c048 CR3: 000000010720a000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0

Comment: your 4th hang actually caught some potentially useful information, but  you didn't include it all. Please edit your question adding 4th hang log data back to the beginning of the event, i.e. back to "---[ begin trace ..." or start trace or similar. Include also about 10 lines prior. The 3rd hang just show NULL characters, which often happens during a crash.

Comment: Thanks, Doug.  I am starting to suspect hardware, and I would love to be wrong.  In any case, here is more data from the fourth hang.  Any insight is greatly appreciated as I am way out of my depth with this..

Comment: The extra info on the fourth hang is above.  Thanks again.

Comment: Your expanded 4th hang still hasn't captured the initial event.

Comment: Doug, Sorry - I went back more than 10 lines before I saw "call trace".  I just pasted in over twice as much.  There are now two call trace incidents included.  Is this enough?

Comment: Your BIOS version, 2311, is many revisions old. Please update to [BIOS version 3801](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-crosshair/rog-crosshair-viii-hero-model/helpdesk_bios), and see it that helps.

Comment: Will do.  A couple of questions, though...  Did the latest data on the fourth hang contain what you said might be 'some potentially useful information'?  Also, is there some reason a machine that had been working fine for months on old BIOS would suddenly begin to hang due to not updating it?

Comment: Yes, it had what I think was the first issue. And, I don't know if the BIOS update will fix you issue or not, but it is where to start. You could also run memtest86 for awhile.

Comment: Several days back, I ran memtester and found problems, placing one of the four DRAM sticks in at a time.  It turned out that TWO sticks were bad.  When I thoroughly tested the remaining two sticks they tested OK.  I thought I had found the problem, but the machine continued to hang on 2 good sticks, and that's when I posted this.  My theory is that I walked across the room with a USB stick.  I always ground it to the case, but one time I touched it to a plastic part and saw a spark when I inserted it.  Must have caused the bad DRAM.  I hope the BIOS update works, else it's the motherboard?

Comment: Bad news - after upgrading the BIOS to 3801, it hung once more.  I have reached the character limit of this, so created a new post 'Frequent System Hangs Requiring Hard Reboot Part 2' which contains the latest syslog.  Any ideas about this would be very appreciated, since this system is unusable at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See 'Frequent System Hangs Requiring Hard Reboot Part 2'.  This problem turned out to be the result of bad DIMMs.  When replaced, the hangs no longer occurred.