# Frequent System Hangs Requiring Hard Reboot Part 2

Tags: 20.04, freeze

This continues from the post [Frequent System Hangs Requiring Hard Reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378895/frequent-system-hangs-requiring-hard-reboot) - no more room available in that post.  After upgrading machine to latest BIOS, it hung again.  Below is the syslog for the latest hang...

**FIFTH HANG**

```
Dec  6 12:17:01 vishnu CRON[88060]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec  6 12:18:21 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121821.647943:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 377.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:18:21 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121821.648019:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 377.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:18:21 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121821.648043:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 377.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:18:21 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121821.714545:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 377.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:18:52 vishnu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[6657]: (EE) client bug: timer event3 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-5ms), your system is too slow
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: invalid cast from 'GtkListStore' to 'GtkTreeView'
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: gtk_tree_view_get_model: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_VIEW (tree_view)' failed
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: invalid cast from 'GtkListStore' to 'GtkTreeView'
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: gtk_tree_view_set_model: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_VIEW (tree_view)' failed
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: invalid cast from 'GtkListStore' to 'GtkTreeView'
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: gtk_tree_view_set_model: assertion 'GTK_IS_TREE_VIEW (tree_view)' failed
Dec  6 12:18:56 vishnu pan[85379]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Dec  6 12:19:33 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121933.367014:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 379.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:19:33 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121933.379279:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 379.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:19:33 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121933.384012:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 379.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:19:33 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: [8568:8568:1206/121933.484359:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 379.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210876] general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x296957f0e66f19c8: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210898] CPU: 9 PID: 6657 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W  OE     5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210903] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO, BIOS 3801 07/30/2021
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210907] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210923] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 33 58 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210927] RSP: 0018:ffffa0e7c436b898 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210931] RAX: 296957f0e66f19c8 RBX: ffff8d0700f20170 RCX: 000000008000900b
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210934] RDX: 0000000000cada36 RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210938] RBP: ffffa0e7c436b8d0 R08: ffff8d0e0ec710c0 R09: 000000000000001a
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210939] R10: ffffa0e7c436ba5d R11: 000000000000001a R12: 296957f0e66f1998
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210941] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8d0700043a00
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210944] FS:  00007ffa54f59ec0(0000) GS:ffff8d0e0ec40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210948] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210952] CR2: 00007ffa46059220 CR3: 000000010bb0e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210955] Call Trace:
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.210964]  ? nvif_object_ctor+0x83/0x160 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211223]  nvif_object_ctor+0x83/0x160 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211266]  nvif_mem_ctor_type+0xc2/0x1a0 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211311]  ? perf_trace_mm_collapse_huge_page_swapin+0xf0/0xf0
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211318]  ? page_counter_uncharge+0x22/0x40
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211321]  ? drain_stock.isra.0+0x68/0xb0
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211326]  ? page_counter_cancel+0x23/0x30
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211330]  nouveau_mem_vram+0xe3/0x180 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211388]  nouveau_vram_manager_new+0x74/0x90 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211443]  ttm_resource_alloc+0x45/0x50 [ttm]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211458]  ttm_bo_mem_space+0xe6/0x330 [ttm]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211463]  ttm_bo_validate+0xf9/0x160 [ttm]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211468]  ttm_bo_init_reserved+0x2b7/0x340 [ttm]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211472]  ttm_bo_init+0x61/0xe0 [ttm]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211477]  ? nouveau_bo_del_io_reserve_lru+0x60/0x60 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211529]  nouveau_bo_init+0xb8/0xd0 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211577]  ? nouveau_bo_del_io_reserve_lru+0x60/0x60 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211625]  nouveau_gem_new+0x7d/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211669]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x100/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211703]  nouveau_gem_ioctl_new+0x5b/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211737]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x100/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211772]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211878]  drm_ioctl+0x257/0x410 [drm]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211892]  ? nouveau_gem_new+0x100/0x100 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211926]  ? __fget_files+0x56/0x80
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211932]  ? __fget_light+0x62/0x80
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211933]  nouveau_drm_ioctl+0x66/0xc0 [nouveau]
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211968]  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x91/0xc0
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211974]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211979]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211985] RIP: 0033:0x7ffa552ec50b
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211988] Code: 0f 1e fa 48 8b 05 85 39 0d 00 64 c7 00 26 00 00 00 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 55 39 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211991] RSP: 002b:00007ffd8a7e67b8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211993] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007ffd8a7e6810 RCX: 00007ffa552ec50b
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211995] RDX: 00007ffd8a7e6810 RSI: 00000000c0306480 RDI: 000000000000000e
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211996] RBP: 00000000c0306480 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000056302a0fd748
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211997] R10: 0000000000000007 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007ffd8a7e6810
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.211999] R13: 000000000000000e R14: 000056302745e400 R15: 0000000000001000
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.212001] Modules linked in: exfat ip6table_filter ip6_tables vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec_realtek intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core nouveau snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus edac_mce_amd snd_pcm_dmaengine joydev drm_ttm_helper snd_pcm input_leds ttm kvm_amd snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi kvm snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul drm_kms_helper ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper ccp snd ucsi_ccg fb_sys_fops syscopyarea efi_pstore typec_ucsi sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore typec mxm_wmi eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof rapl k10temp mac_hid sch_fq_codel nct6775 hwmon_vid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ses enclosure scsi_transport_sas hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.212072]  hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage mfd_aaeon asus_wmi sparse_keymap video crc32_pclmul igb i2c_algo_bit i2c_nvidia_gpu r8169 dca nvme i2c_piix4 ahci xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas libahci realtek nvme_core wmi
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.212097] ---[ end trace 4769e2453a6865f8 ]---
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452621] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452664] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 33 58 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452669] RSP: 0018:ffffa0e7c436b898 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452673] RAX: 296957f0e66f19c8 RBX: ffff8d0700f20170 RCX: 000000008000900b
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452675] RDX: 0000000000cada36 RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452677] RBP: ffffa0e7c436b8d0 R08: ffff8d0e0ec710c0 R09: 000000000000001a
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452678] R10: ffffa0e7c436ba5d R11: 000000000000001a R12: 296957f0e66f1998
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452679] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8d0700043a00
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452680] FS:  00007ffa54f59ec0(0000) GS:ffff8d0e0ec40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452681] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  6 12:19:37 vishnu kernel: [112554.452682] CR2: 00007ffa46059220 CR3: 000000010bb0e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Dec  6 12:19:40 vishnu gnome-shell[8567]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558530] general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x296957f0e66f19c8: 0000 [#2] SMP NOPTI
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558542] CPU: 9 PID: 87845 Comm: ghb Tainted: G      D W  OE     5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558546] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO, BIOS 3801 07/30/2021
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558549] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558568] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 33 58 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558570] RSP: 0018:ffffa0e7c7d7fca8 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558574] RAX: 296957f0e66f19c8 RBX: 0000000008000002 RCX: 0000000000000000
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558577] RDX: 0000000000cada3f RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558579] RBP: ffffa0e7c7d7fce0 R08: ffff8d0e0ec710c0 R09: 0000000000000000
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558580] R10: ffffffffa7d69190 R11: 000000000000002c R12: 296957f0e66f1998
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558581] R13: 0000000000404cc0 R14: ffff8d07963f2780 R15: ffff8d0700043a00
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558582] FS:  00007f759b7fe700(0000) GS:ffff8d0e0ec40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558584] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558586] CR2: 00007f792e9ae004 CR3: 0000000154de8000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558588] Call Trace:
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558597]  ? inotify_handle_inode_event+0x7e/0x210
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558615]  inotify_handle_inode_event+0x7e/0x210
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558618]  fsnotify_handle_inode_event.isra.0+0x7c/0xa0
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558622]  fsnotify+0x4d2/0x550
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558624]  __fsnotify_parent+0x203/0x310
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558626]  vfs_write+0x16d/0x280
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558636]  ? vfs_write+0x16d/0x280
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558638]  ksys_write+0x67/0xe0
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558640]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558642]  do_syscall_64+0x38/0x90
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558650]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558658] RIP: 0033:0x7f79621f33a7
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558663] Code: 44 00 00 41 54 55 49 89 d4 53 48 89 f5 89 fb 48 83 ec 10 e8 5b fd ff ff 4c 89 e2 41 89 c0 48 89 ee 89 df b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 35 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 94 fd ff ff 48
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558665] RSP: 002b:00007f759b7fd0c0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558667] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000017 RCX: 00007f79621f33a7
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558669] RDX: 0000000000040000 RSI: 00007f75a4198140 RDI: 0000000000000017
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558670] RBP: 00007f75a4198140 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000040000
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558671] R10: 000000000000002c R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000040000
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558672] R13: 0000000000040000 R14: 0000000000040000 R15: 0000000000000005
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558675] Modules linked in: exfat ip6table_filter ip6_tables vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr snd_hda_codec_realtek intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core nouveau snd_hwdep soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus edac_mce_amd snd_pcm_dmaengine joydev drm_ttm_helper snd_pcm input_leds ttm kvm_amd snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi kvm snd_seq crct10dif_pclmul drm_kms_helper ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper ccp snd ucsi_ccg fb_sys_fops syscopyarea efi_pstore typec_ucsi sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore typec mxm_wmi eeepc_wmi wmi_bmof rapl k10temp mac_hid sch_fq_codel nct6775 hwmon_vid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ses enclosure scsi_transport_sas hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558756]  hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage mfd_aaeon asus_wmi sparse_keymap video crc32_pclmul igb i2c_algo_bit i2c_nvidia_gpu r8169 dca nvme i2c_piix4 ahci xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas libahci realtek nvme_core wmi
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.558779] ---[ end trace 4769e2453a6865f9 ]---
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773132] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x116/0x470
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773157] Code: 08 65 4c 03 05 33 39 33 58 49 83 78 10 00 4d 8b 20 0f 84 fa 02 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 f1 02 00 00 41 8b 47 28 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f b8 00 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773162] RSP: 0018:ffffa0e7c436b898 EFLAGS: 00010202
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773167] RAX: 296957f0e66f19c8 RBX: ffff8d0700f20170 RCX: 000000008000900b
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773169] RDX: 0000000000cada36 RSI: 0000000000000cc0 RDI: 00000000000310c0
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773171] RBP: ffffa0e7c436b8d0 R08: ffff8d0e0ec710c0 R09: 000000000000001a
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773172] R10: ffffa0e7c436ba5d R11: 000000000000001a R12: 296957f0e66f1998
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773174] R13: 0000000000000cc0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8d0700043a00
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773175] FS:  00007f759b7fe700(0000) GS:ffff8d0e0ec40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773178] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Dec  6 12:19:42 vishnu kernel: [112559.773179] CR2: 00007f792e9ae004 CR3: 0000000154de8000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
```

**@heynnema**

MORE DATA

Yes, I began with 4 DIMMS (total 64G), this seemed to fine for months, then this problem seemed to start about a week ago.  And, yes, there are only 2 now (16G each, for a total of 32G Memory).

$ free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       6.8Gi       299Mi        69Mi        24Gi        23Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       3.0Mi       2.0Gi
```

$ sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60

$ sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 3801
       date: 07/30/2021
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 3b
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3600C19-16GTRS
          vendor: G Skill Intl
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_A1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3600C19-16GTRS
          vendor: G Skill Intl
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_B1
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_B2
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 3e
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 3f
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 40
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 64MiB
       capacity: 64MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

$ ls -al /var/crash

```
total 187812
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie      4096 Dec  6 11:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root          4096 Jul 31  2020 ..
-rw-r-----  1 j2b      whoopsie  24935135 Nov 30 12:46 _opt_brave.com_brave_brave.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 j2b      whoopsie         0 Nov 30 12:47 _opt_brave.com_brave_brave.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        37 Nov 30 12:47 _opt_brave.com_brave_brave.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 j2b      whoopsie   1848395 Nov 28 10:29 _usr_bin_eog.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 j2b      whoopsie   3812687 Nov 30 06:19 _usr_bin_file-roller.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 j2b      whoopsie  22866234 Dec  1 17:28 _usr_bin_ghb.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 j2b      whoopsie 134983097 Dec  6 11:34 _usr_bin_pan.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 j2b      whoopsie         0 Dec  1 04:38 _usr_bin_pan.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        37 Dec  1 04:47 _usr_bin_pan.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 j2b      whoopsie   3843997 Nov 28 09:49 _usr_share_apport_apport-checkreports.1000.crash
```

$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

ls: cannot access '/home/j2b/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 31  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 23 15:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 18 02:17 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 18 07:57 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 18 07:57 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Thank you very much for looking at this for me.  -j2b

Comment: AMD Ryzen processors have notorious memory compatibility issues. How many DIMMS did you start with before you found two that failed `memtest`... four? So you have two DIMMS installed now, correct? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `ls -al /var/crash`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: And also show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema  The info you requested is above since it is too long for a comment. Thank you for you help.  I noticed you edited my question to make it more readable.  if there is a trick to keep it from stripping line-enders, please let me know. -j2b

Comment: Yes, when you paste in a block of structured text, select that text, then click the {} icon to format it to human-readable.

Comment: Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

Comment: The two remaining DIMMS are in the wrong slots. They're in slot: DIMM_A1 and A2, and they should be in A1 and B1. Rerun `memtest` after moving them.

Comment: Your gnome-shell extensions look fine.

Comment: Your BIOS is current.

Comment: @heynnema - No, neither RAM nor CPU are overclocked.  I got a gamer board because it supported the M.2 SSD, but I am not a gamer - I video edit and 3D model.  I ordered replacement DIMMs and they arrived this afternoon.  Rather than moving the DIMMs as you suggested, can I just add the two new DIMMS in the other two slots and run memtester?  Any idea how 2 DIMMS could go bad? Could having the remaining DIMMS in the wrong slots have caused the hangs?  If not, any idea what the problem is? I really don't want to have to replace the motherboard, but I've memtested the RAM and fscked the SSDs.

Comment: Populate the A1 and B1 slots first, with the remaining original DIMMS. Then put the new DIMMS into A2 and B2.

Comment: @heynnema - I did as you suggested after independently testing all four sticks of RAM.  I will not feel comfortable until this machine runs without hanging for at least 3 days.  Thank you again for your help.  I know you don't know, but could you take an educated guess as to what could be going on here?

Comment: Too early to say for sure. Keep me posted.

Comment: @heynnema - Thank you once again for your help - very appreciated.  I have now let this machine run for a week.  No hangs, no crashes, so it appears fixed. It seems it was initially bad RAM and then when I discovered this and removed the two bad sticks, the remaining sticks were not in the proper slots.  The thing that continues to nag at me is - how in the world did TWO sticks of RAM go bad?  Could static charge on a USB thumb drive damage RAM but not the motherboard?  Because fortunately, the motherboard seems OK as evidenced by no problems for a week now?

Comment: Great news! I put together a quick answer to document our findings. Please feel free to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks! You may wish to close out/document/delete Part #1 of this series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

**Part #1 of question**: [Frequent System Hangs Requiring Hard Reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378895/frequent-system-hangs-requiring-hard-reboot)

**AMD Ryzen 9 3950X**

**G Skill Intl F4-3600C19-16GTRS 16G DIMMS**

**Note**: AMD Ryzen processors have notorious memory compatibility issues.

`Memtest` (https://www.memtest86.com/ ) called out two bad DIMMS.

Replaced the two DIMMS and it's been running fine for one week now.